# Why the EventSubscriber doesn't work in symfony 2 framework

Tags: php, symfony

I have the problem with an `eventSubscribers` in Symfony 2 framework. I've written this code:

`src/MyBundle/UserBundle/EventListener/UsernameProfileEditExternalListener.php`

```
class UsernameProfileEditExternalListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

protected $userExternalForumRepository;
protected $userExternalDatesRepository;

public function __construct(UserExternalForumRepository $userExternalForumRepository, UserExternalDatesRepository $userExternalDatesRepository) {
    $this->userExternalForumRepository = $userExternalForumRepository;
    $this->userExternalDatesRepository = $userExternalDatesiRepository;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(
        'mybundle.user.change_username' => 'onEditUsername',
    );
}

public function onEditUsername(FormEvent $event) {
    die('It\'s working!');
}
```

I added this code to the file `src/MyBundle/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`:

```
username_profile_edit_listener:
    class: MyBundle\UserBundle\EventListener\UsernameProfileEditExternalListener
    arguments: [@user_external_forum_repository, @user_external_dates_repository]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, event: mybundle.user.change_username, method: onEditUsername }
```

And in this file `src\AppBundle\Controller\Backend\UserController.php` I dispatch this event:

```
$dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');


$event = new FormEvent($usernameForm, $request);
$dispatcher->dispatch('mybundle.user.change_username', $event);
```

But it doesn't work. I completely don't now why. I will be very grateful for pieces of advice. I'm a very beginner in Symfony. Can `services.yml` file be caching?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Could you please provide more information on that?

Comment: The method "onEditUsername()" isn't call. If I good thinking, after dispatch "mybundle.user.change_username" event, the method "onEditUsername()" should be called.

Comment: Post the code where you're setting the `$dispatcher` variable

Comment: 'myBundle' in getSubscribedEvents() vs mybundle in the name that is being dispatched  - one has a capital 'B'. I've taken to use `ClassName::class` to identify what is being dispatched, and caught.

Comment: In your example you use: `mybundle.user.change_username` when dispatching but in your subscriber's `getSubscribedEvents` you use `myBundle.user.change_username` (notice the uppercase B in Bundle). Could that be it?

Comment: @JasonRoman I've updated my post.
I'm setting $dispatcher variable in this file "src\AppBundle\Controller\Backend\UserController.php"

Comment: There is no need for an event or method fields in services.yml for an event subscriber though I'm not sure it that is the problem.  Try adding a die to getSubscribedEvents to verify it is being called.  And do the ever popular cache clear.  There is also a bin/console debug:event-dispatcher command.

Comment: @Cerad i added die to getSubscribedEvents and it doesn't work

Comment: @dbrumann You have right, but this error was only the example on this post, in real code is it ok. I updated the post.

Comment: You do have a MyBundle extension that is loading your services file?

Comment: Ok, it is working pretty well. I had to clear the cache. Thanks all for advices.